# How to use Ninject in WPF application

Tags: wpf, ninject

I'm familiar with MVC but I'm trying to learn WPF with Ninject. Can some one give me some example or reference?

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with WPF, except in case you want to instanciate ViewModels using ninject.
One of the things the first page(s) of ninject doc skip are the instanciation a Kernel: `var kernel = new StandardKernel(); kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>(); kernel.Get<IFoo>();" <-- this is kernel instanciation, binding, and instanciating in one tiny example.

Comment: About file placement: Which file are you talking about? The ninject library (dll)? Your source code? The ninject library is best integrated by using the Nuget package manager and your source code can be located wherever you want, provided you can access it from application (referenced as project / library).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As I said in my comment to your OP, all the information you require is available within the [Ninject documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Getting-Started).  That said it could be argued that it is easy to get lost within its vast documentation if you are unfamiliar with Ninject and/or DI.

There are a few tutorials online of which [this one](http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2012/07/28/A-step-by-step-guide-to-using-Ninject-for-dependancy-injection-in-C-sharp.aspx) I thought was particularly informative.  Whilst it provides an example using a `console application`, the principles of how `Ninject` works remain the same.

Irrespective of your application type you configure your container at your application entry point;

- Console app - `Main`
- WPF - `App` (unless you are using a framework in which case you may provide a custom bootstrapper)
- ASP.NET - No idea, perhaps someone could enlighten me

---

**DISCLAIMER** I do not claim to be an authority on `Ninject` or `DI`, below is simply a quick example of how I understand these two objects *can* be used in conjunction with one another.

For example sake, let us work with the examples provided in the Ninject documentation.

**1)** Create a WPF application named `NinjectIoC`

**2)** Use Nuget to add a reference to the `Ninject` project

**3)** Open `App.xaml` and remove the `StartupUri` property from the `Application` element so that your `App.xaml` looks like below:

```
<Application x:Class="NinjectIoC.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The reason we do this is because the `StartupUri` property informs the `WPF` application which UI control to initially display when the application starts.  We are going to use `Ninject` to display our initial UI control.

**4)** Open `App.xaml.cs`.  This is where we are going to configure the `Ninject` `container`, or `Kernel` to use `Ninject` terminology.  We `override` the application `OnStartup` method so that we may configure our `container` and subsequently initialise the application as we would like.  Update the content of your `App.xaml.cs` to look as follows:

```
namespace NinjectIoC
{
    using Ninject;
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class App
    {
        private IKernel container;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            ConfigureContainer();
            ComposeObjects();
            Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        private void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            this.container = new StandardKernel();
            container.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().InTransientScope();
        }

        private void ComposeObjects()
        {
            Current.MainWindow = this.container.Get<MainWindow>();
            Current.MainWindow.Title = "DI with Ninject";
        }
    }
}
```

A brief explination:

**4.1)** `OnStartup - Override the`OnStartup`method so that we may configure our`container` and initialise the application as we desire.

**4.2)** `ConfigureContainer` - Inform our `container` of how we would like to resolve our concrete types.  There is far more to this than I have displayed in this example, however, there is far more to this than I have shown.  There are topics such as [Multi Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection), [Binding Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Conventions-Based-Binding) and [Kernel Modules](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) for which you are best learning about it from the [official documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject).

**4.3)** `ComposeObjects` - Having removed the `StartupUri` property from `App.xaml` we must inform the application which UI control we would like it to use for the `MainWindow`.  Alongside asking our `container` to use `MainWindow` as our `MainWindow` we set the `Title` property too.  Again you might want to do other tasks here for manual object composition.

You do not have to separate out the steps as I have above, for this contrived example it would make more sense not to bother.  As your application grows and you start to do more sophisticated things with the `container`, separating some of the stages out begins to make the `container` configuration more manageable.  The choice is yours.

**5)** Next open `MainWindow.xaml`, then copy and paste the following:

```
<Window x:Class="NinjectIoC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="78" Width="362">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="269,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Attack"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Target" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I shall not bother explaining the above as it should be obvious what is going on.

**6)** Finally open `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and update it as follows:

```
namespace NinjectIoC
{
    using System.Windows;

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly IWeapon weapon;

        public MainWindow(IWeapon weapon)
        {
            this.weapon = weapon;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Attack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.weapon.Hit(this.Target.Text);
        }
    }

    public class Sword : IWeapon
    {
        public void Hit(string target)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"I swing and thrust my sword about like a mad man at " + target);
        }
    }

    public interface IWeapon
    {
        void Hit(string target);
    }
}
```

Again I will make this brief as what is happening above has nothing to do with the configuration of `Ninject` and it should once again be obvious what is happening.

The main thing to notice in the above is the `argument` that the `MainWindow` constructor expects; `IWeapon`.  You might be asking yourself *How does that get resolved as I am not creating a concrete implementation of `Weapon` anywhere?*

Well during the `ConfigureContainer` method in `App.xaml.cs` we informed the `container` how we would like it to resolve dependencies for `IWeapon`:

```
container.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().InTransientScope();
```

The above tells the `container` that anywhere it encounters a dependency for `IWeapon` we would like it to provide an instance of `Weapon`.  Upon requesting the `container` resolve (`Get`) our initial `MainWindow` control, using the following:

```
Current.MainWindow = this.container.Get<MainWindow>();
```

The `container` took a look at its constructors and determined the constructor with the most arguments it understood.  In this example it was the constructor that required an implementation of `IWeapon` and oh look, the `container` knows how to resolve this dependency because we told it how to do so earlier in `ConfigureContainer`.

Assuming neither you nor I have made any mistakes with the above code, pressing `F5` should launch the application and you should see a small window with a `TextBox` and `Button`.  Enter something in to the `TextBox` then press the `Button` and you should see a `MessageBox` control informing you that you swang your sword like a `"mad man"` at whoever or whatever you entered in the `TextBox`.

---

There is far more to both `Ninject` and `DI` than I have described here.  For example there are entire books on the subject of `DI` such as [this one by Mark Seeman](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1387275916&sr=8-1&keywords=dependency+injection+in+.net).

Hopefully the above will give you at basic starting point of where to look and where to go to progress further with your adventures with `Ninject` and `DI`.

Comment: @noviankristianto - I am glad to be of help.  If you found my answer useful, please consider either an upvote or marking it as the answer both for myself and the community.  [:

Comment: Good and Simple. I am using similar approach but I also need to access the container in other parts of my application. I know passing it as a parameter is not a good idea. Is there something better?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is too simplistic for me to upvote. We know that we can manually resolve a component from the kernel. The challenge in the WPF world would be to automatically resolve resources via IOC in XAML.

Comment: Uh, this was a good quality post that explained the ins and outs of the basic use. If its not useful to you, then just move on. No need for belittlement.

Comment: The recommended Ninject tutorial link above was dead.  I found it on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine, here:  https://web.archive.org/web/20150328180847/http://www.christiaanverwijs.nl/post/2012/07/28/A-step-by-step-guide-to-using-Ninject-for-dependancy-injection-in-C-sharp.aspx